# R: fill matrix according to condition

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

There are only two charging stations for electric vehicles at the parking.
It is known the time of arrival and leaving of the cars, and charging time.
Only two cars can be charged at the same time.

```
    car<-rep(1:5)
arrival<-c("8:00","8:00", "9:00","10:00","10:00")
leaving<-c("10:00","12:00", "11:00", "11:00", "12:00")
charging_time_h<-c(2,4,2,1,2)
df<-cbind(car,arrival, leaving, charging_time_h)
```

[image]

```
#Staying time at the parking

mat1<-matrix(0, ncol = 7, nrow = 5)
colnames(mat1) <- c("8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00")
rownames(mat1) <- c(1:5)

for(i in 1:length(car)) mat1[i,which(colnames(mat1) == arrival[i]):which(colnames(mat1) == leaving[i])]=1

mat1 <- rbind(mat1, 'Cars at th eparking' = colSums(mat1))
```

[image]

"Cars at the parking" - the total number of cars at the parking at the same time.

If the third car arrives while both charging stations are occupied, it can wait for the next free charging station.
If the third car leaves the parking earlier, it remains uncharged. 
As a result, I would like to get that matrix:
[image]

The 4th car left the parking uncharged - state "FALSE".
The 5th car is “TRUE/FALSE” because the charging could not complete.
Could You please help me?

Thank You very much in advance!
Best regards,
Inna